# How to move section number and section into margin with scrbook without titlesec

Tags: sectioning, indentation, scrbook

I need to move section number and section heading as shown in figure below.

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside=semi]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=42pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use

```
\addtokomafont{section}{\addtolength\leftskip{-40pt}}
```

But the left margin in your example is only 42pt.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside=semi,headings=small]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm,
  left=42pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt,
  marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt,
  textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt}

\addtokomafont{section}{\addtolength\leftskip{-40pt}}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's just as good to use `\addtokomafont{section}{\hspace*{-40pt}}`.

Comment: @Werner If a section title is longer then one line `\addtokomafont{section}{\hspace*{-40pt}}` only shifts the first line of this section title.